# Listview with icons

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an listview with Icons. Email and star.
 Now at runtime I will be populating an image and if no image is there then I want to show no icon or an transparent image. Now my problem is that I have sent an transparent image by default and for the rest I populate an Icon. But when the List is clicked then an empty space is seen.
 Have a look at the image below.

[image]

When the item is selected the empty icon is seen.

can some one help me for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about set that image's visibility to "gone" or "invisiblie"?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a transparent image, set the visibily of the image to GONE (and add margin to the image below if star is gone)

Comment: or set the image to invisible so you don't need more margin

Comment: I wasn't cover the background, but I've tried and it didn't. So you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Let me update the Kingori's answer properly.

Just set the visibility as "Visible" whenever image is available:

=> `iconImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

And set the visibility as "Invisible" or "Gone" whenever image is NOT available.

=> `iconImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`